# Visual circuit simulation on a Mac

Tags: ltspice, spice, software, cad, apple

I am currently trying to design a circuit on a Mac (some might say therein lies my problem). 
My goal is simply to *design a rudimentary implementation of the circuit which I can visualise working*
I have tried:

1. [Tinkercad circuits](https://www.tinkercad.com/)
2. the Falstad JavaScript (or desktop
   version) [circuit simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/)
3. downloading LTSpice for
   Mac.

The problem with 1) and 2) are that as soon as I start working with larger arrangements they start to bog down and stutter, both become unusable.
In terms of using LTSpice I am keen but I cannot find any suitable models for components such as a shift registers, 7 segment displays etc.

One point of intrigue with respect to this problem has been the [NXP SimKit](https://www.nxp.com/support/developer-resources/models-and-test-data/simkit/source-code-library:SOURCE-CODE-LIBRARY) but I cannot even start to decipher whether it would work with LTSpice for Mac, can anyone help?

Comment: You're doing only digital simulation, or do you want to do analog/mixed mode too?  [Logisim](http://www.cburch.com/logisim/) is very popular, but a bit old and no longer being updated, and [Digital](https://github.com/hneemann/Digital) has been designed as a replacement for it; both are implemented in Java so should run fine on a Mac. Both only do digital simulations, though.

Comment: Regarding LTspice's rather eclectic selection of libraries: remember that it's supplied by Linear Technologies with the express intention to help you design power supplies using their SMPS ICs -- any other application it may have is not officially supported.  This explains a lot about what it does and doesn't include...

Comment: @Jules I don't want to speak too soon as I have been searching (and attempting to make many different things work) for a fair while but that looks very promising! Looking at the screenshots it seems as if there is comprehensive componentry to choose from, given that the models are built-in

Comment: There is a library for CDxxxx ICs, search for it on the Yahoo LTspice Group, or on ltwiki.org. Otherwise, you can build those out of the basic elements found in the `[Digital]` folder (in the "place element" dialog). But, really, if you're after digital, then @Jules 's suggestion is better.